# Timer is not implemented the first time

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a timer and it works fine for the most part.. 
But for the first time , the clock isn't starting but for the rest of the activity it is, 
The oncreate method has some problem which I am not able to figure out..Help!

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.friends);
    Splash.one_time = false;
    initilize(); 
    mytime = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            timer();
        }
    };
    mytime.start();
    mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (count_down > 0) {
                if (count_down <= 5)
                    clock.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                else
                    clock.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                clock.setText(String.format("%d", count_down--));
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            } else {
                clock.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                clock.setText("0");
                timeout();
            }
        }
    };
}

private void timer() {
    mStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `mytime.start();` before creating `mUpdateTimeTask`, in `onCreate()`. So the method `timer()` passes an uninitialized `mUpdateTimeTask` to `mHandler`.

You should initialize first and then start your `Thread`:

```
mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
   ...
};

mytime.start();
```